# Keras EarlyStopping callback on val_auc running mysteriously

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

## Simple DL GridsearchCV modelling using Keras

```
epochs = [1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26, 31, 36, 41, 46]
batch_size = [2,4]

stopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_auc', patience= 10, mode = 'max', min_delta = 1, restore_best_weights=True)
save_mod = ModelCheckpoint(r'C:\......................\best_model.h5', monitor='val_acc', mode='max', save_best_only=True, save_freq = 'epoch')

param_grid = dict(epochs = epochs, batch_size = batch_size)

def create_classify_model(learn_rate = 0.01, momentum = 0):
            # create model
            network = Sequential()
            #input layer and 1st hidden layer
            network.add(Dense(units = data_seg.x_tr.shape[1], activation="relu", input_shape = 
(data_seg.x_tr.shape[1],)))

            #dropout layer for input layer
            network.add(Dropout(0.2, input_shape = (data_seg.x_tr.shape[1],)))

            #second hidden layer
            network.add(Dense(units = math.trunc(data_seg.x_tr.shape[1]*0.8), activation = "relu"))

            #dropout layer for hidden layer
            network.add(Dropout(0.5))

            #output layer
            network.add(Dense(units = len(np.unique(data_seg.y_tr)), activation = "softmax"))

            optimizer = SGD(lr=learn_rate, momentum=momentum)

            #compiling neural network
            network.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = optimizer, metrics = 
['acc',auc_metric()])

            return network

neural_network = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_classify_model, workers = -1, use_multiprocessing = 
True, verbose=2)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=neural_network, param_grid=param_grid)

fit_params = dict(callbacks=[stopper, save_mod], validation_split = 0.05)

grid_model = grid.fit(data_seg.x_tr, data_seg.y_tr, **fit_params)
```

## Output

```
471/471 - 1s - loss: 0.7568 - acc: 0.6019 - auc: 0.6357 - val_loss: 0.4909 - val_acc: 0.7600 - 
val_auc: 0.8676
125/125 - 0s - loss: 0.5264 - acc: 0.7751 - auc: 0.8459
WARNING:tensorflow:Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_auc` which is not available. Available 
metrics are: loss,acc,auc_1,val_loss,val_acc,val_auc_1
472/472 - 1s - loss: 0.7242 - acc: 0.6288 - auc_1: 0.6494 - val_loss: 0.5680 - val_acc: 0.7000 - 
val_auc_1: 0.7896
124/124 - 0s - loss: 0.6316 - acc: 0.6250 - auc_1: 0.6942
WARNING:tensorflow:Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_auc` which is not available. Available 
metrics are: loss,acc,auc_2,val_loss,val_acc,val_auc_2
472/472 - 1s - loss: 0.7193 - acc: 0.6182 - auc_2: 0.6563 - val_loss: 0.5279 - val_acc: 0.7400 - 
val_auc_2: 0.8544
124/124 - 0s - loss: 0.5929 - acc: 0.7863 - auc_2: 0.7995
WARNING:tensorflow:Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_auc` which is not available. Available 
metrics are: loss,acc,auc_3,val_loss,val_acc,val_auc_3
472/472 - 1s - loss: 0.7060 - acc: 0.6299 - auc_3: 0.6649 - val_loss: 0.5369 - val_acc: 0.8000 - 
val_auc_3: 0.8400
124/124 - 0s - loss: 0.5564 - acc: 0.7661 - auc_3: 0.8305
WARNING:tensorflow:Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_auc` which is not available. Available 
metrics are: loss,acc,auc_4,val_loss,val_acc,val_auc_4
472/472 - 1s - loss: 0.7258 - acc: 0.6161 - auc_4: 0.6398 - val_loss: 0.5676 - val_acc: 0.7400 - 
val_auc_4: 0.7936
```

The ouput here, showcases that the val_auc metric which has been used to monitor EarlyStopping has been given an integer value, which increases with every batch end I suppose. Hence, can someone help me understand about how can I monitor the val_auc in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bump up the TensorFlow version, this is an issue of TensorFlow 1.14. Update your TensorFlow to 2.1 and your problem will be solved.

A case in point, a similar problem happened to: [Why is history storing auc and val_auc with incrementing integers (auc_2, auc_4, ...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63585285/why-is-history-storing-auc-and-val-auc-with-incrementing-integers-auc-2-auc-4/63592239#63592239), the solution was to update to TF 2.1(was using TF 1.14)

Comment: I actually have TensorFlow v2.3.0 running, hence should I rather bring it down to v2.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Run tf.keras.backend.clear_session() before creating the model again.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/clear_session